# ggplot2 geom_density limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I remove the lines at the end of the limits in calls to `geom_density`?

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

dfGamma = data.frame(nu75 = rgamma(100, 0.75),
           nu1 = rgamma(100, 1),
           nu2 = rgamma(100, 2))

dfGamma = stack(dfGamma)
ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x = values)) + 
  geom_density(aes(group = ind, color = ind))
```

which produces,
[image]

How would I get rid of the vertical blue lines at the edges of the plot, and the horizontal one running along the x-axis?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `stat_density()` instead of `geom_density()` and add arguments `geom="line"` and `position="identity"`.

```
ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x = values)) + 
  stat_density(aes(group = ind, color = ind),position="identity",geom="line")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way that seems to produce identical results:

```
ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x = values, color=ind)) + geom_line(stat="density")
```