# How can I change the legend of this figure?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code to produce the picture:

```
ggplot() + 
stat_density(kernel = "biweight",aes(x=fd, colour='red'), data=dw,position="identity",geom="line") + 
stat_density(kernel = "biweight",aes(x=fd, colour='blue'), data=ds,position="identity",geom="line")+
stat_density(kernel = "biweight",aes(x=fd, colour='orange'), data=dmw,position="identity",geom="line")+
stat_density(kernel = "biweight", aes(x=fd, colour='green'), data=dne,position="identity",geom="line")+
scale_colour_manual(name='Regions',values=c('red'='red', 'blue'='blue', 'orange'='orange', 'green'='green'), labels=c('West','South','Midwest','Northeast'))+
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,0.025)) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200))
```

Now,

1. <del>How do I remove the green line in the y and x-axis? I am not sure why it is there.</del> (Solved)
2. How do I change the legend box to just a dot of the color?
3. <del>How can I make the bottom of the figure to start from y=0 instead of empty space there?</del> (Solved)

Thank you.

P.S. Not able to use MELT for the dataframes because they are of different lengths but same name 'fd'.

[image]

Comment: Your first question is an easily found [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17006956/324364).

Comment: Could you please give a link here? I am not sure what keyword to search.

Comment: There's a link embedded in my comment. I simply searched for "ggplot2 geom_density bottom line", and that question was the first result. Your third question is answered either the same way you achieved that result for the x axis, or by noticing the `expand` argument in the docs.

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17006956/324364
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456816/ggplot2-change-legend-symbol
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220424/ggplot2-bar-plot-no-space-between-bottom-of-geom-and-x-axis-keep-space-above

Comment: Thank you. Now I can get a line in there. But still not sure, how to get a dot.

Comment: I have solved 1 and 3. Thank you. But not 2.

Comment: For 2 - you can maybe get a workaround from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356052/control-ggplot2-legend-look-without-affecting-the-plot